# Совет по оптимальной работе с javascript массивами

Tags: массивы, ajax, javascript, база-данных

Здравствуйте!
Передо мой стоит задача сделать в панели администрирования сайта вывод пользователей в виде таблички с постраничной навигацией. Табличка сделана AJAX.
Как лучше сделать: при переходе на новую страницу, в табличке, давать запрос серверу на получение 15 клиентов ( 15 это столько выводить в табличке ), ИЛИ лучше в начале работы скрипта выгрузить всех клиентов в javascript массив и потом просто отображать нужные?

Предполагается, что в БД несколько тысяч клиентов. Важны параметры производительность/нагрузка на сервер.

Спасибо.

Comment: конечно же пусть клиент апгрейдит свое железо, и пофиг что браузер вешается, сервер то не казенный.

Comment: а как вам компромисс между этими двумя подходами -  загружать данные допустим на 3 страницы, т.о. пока пользователь будет просматривать первые, остальные несколько будут уже предзагружены и так далее

Comment: @Spectre сомневаюсь, что это будет высоконагруженный проект, при грамотной архитектуре аякс запрос на 15 позиций будет обрабатываться очень быстро, не забываем что mysql запросы кэшируются. записей то всего несколько тысяч, о какой нагрузке на сервер может идти речь?

Comment: В будущем этом будет высоконагруженный проект (надеюсь). И дело еще в том что есть еще несколько таблиц и в них тоже по несколько тысяч элементов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от логики обработки данных в многопользовательской системе.

Возможно наиболее логичным (во многих случаях) является такой подход. Вы делаете запрос к базе и помещаете результат в таблицу. Далее результат уже не будет меняться при изменении остальных данных в базе.

Этот результат Вы выводите постранично, каждый раз читаете новую порцию. В конце обработки (новый запрос той же страницы или logout) Вы эти результаты удаляете.

Иначе, пока пользователь читал первый экран, а потом болтал по телефону, информация на пятом экране может уже сильно логически не соответствовать прочитанной на первом.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше загружать постранично через аякс, чем загрузить несколько тысяч данных и ждать перехода.